# command not foundbles-config error on service firewall restart

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

This is a follow-up question after I fixed my initial problems:
I have a CENTOS Linux VPS.
I have the following in my IPTABLES script to run when my VPN restarts, but I get errors when I do a `service firewall restart`

I've ran each of the commands below manually and they work. 
According to Host Gator in order for the IPTABLES rules to persist I need to place them in the

```
/etc/firewall/INCLUDE
```

Here is my INCLUDE file:

```
  1 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
  2 iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
  3 iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
  4 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
  5 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  6 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5622  -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
  7 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80  -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
  8 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4643  -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
  9 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22  -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
 10 iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
 11 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
 12 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 --syn -j ACCEPT
 13 iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
 14 iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
 15 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
 16 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
 17 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
 18 iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p ALL
```

Errors:

```
DETECTED CONTROL PANEL: cpanel
Reading file /etc/firewall/GLOBAL_DROP
Running file /etc/firewall/INCLUDE
REG INCOMING SERVICES
Reading file /etc/firewall/INPUT
OUTGOING SERVICES
Reading file /etc/firewall/OUTPUT
: command not foundbles-config: line 7:
: command not foundbles-config: line 14:
: command not foundbles-config: line 20:
: command not foundbles-config: line 26:
: command not foundbles-config: line 33:
: command not foundbles-config: line 38:
: command not foundbles-config: line 44:
: command not foundbles-config: line 49:
```

Is this some sort of spacing issue or whitespaces? Any ideas?

Comment: the IPTABLE rules seem to be functioning as far as I can tell, but I can only tell by the port forwarding. I've contacted Host Gator and hopefully they will be able to help. I like to think that I pay their bloated VPS prices for the support they give me.

Comment: The error message doesn't refer to `/etc/firewall/INCLUDE`, it refers to `/etc/firewall/OUTPUT`.  Could you add the contents of that file into your question?

Comment: The OUTPUT file is completely blank (I viewed it using VIM).

Answer (score 0):

A HostGator Linux Admin fixed the problem:
According to HostGator:

The error message was corrected by moving a file that has incorrect configuration options and then restarting the firewall:

```
root@mic [~]# mv -v /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config /root
`/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config' -> `/root/iptables-config'
root@mic [~]# service firewall restart
DETECTED CONTROL PANEL: cpanel
Reading file /etc/firewall/GLOBAL_DROP
Running file /etc/firewall/INCLUDE
REG INCOMING SERVICES
Reading file /etc/firewall/INPUT
OUTGOING SERVICES
Reading file /etc/firewall/OUTPUT 
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[ OK ]
```